# Is there is a way to restrict the choices to datalist in input type=color and disable the other... option?

Tags: css, html, input, colors, html-datalist

The code below generates the dropdown to choose the colors from the datalist but  also give an 'other' option. I want to restrict the choice of colors to the ones I provide as options.

```
<input type="color" id="some id" name="someName" list="rainbow" value="#FF0000">
<datalist id="rainbow">
    <option value="#FF0000">Red</option>
    <option value="#FFA500">Orange</option>
    <option value="#FFFF00">Yellow</option>
    <option value="#008000">Green</option>
    <option value="#0000FF">Blue</option>
    <option value="#4B0082">Indigo</option>
    <option value="#EE82EE">Violet</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Hmmm...that does not seem to be an option..no pun intended.

Comment: @Paulie_D The "other" option is added by the browser (chrome anyway) automatically because the input type is a color

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate this isn't really an answer, but it's a bit too detailed for a comment :)

The list of options only renders at all on Chrome, Opera, and Android anyway. In Firefox it's just a colour-wheel, and in Internet Explorer, Safari, Edge, iOS, Windows Phone, and Opera Mini it's a horribly non-user-friendly textbox into which the user has to type the hex codes, with no default options provided.

Assuming you are only providing a small number of colours to choose from, and since you have no need for the colour-wheel functionality even on the 4 browsers that support it, wouldn't you be better off just offering a list of radio buttons? A bit of CSS and a sprinkling of JS and this looks decent all the way back to IE8:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Color example</title>
        <style>
            .color label {
                border-right: solid 1.4em #ddd;
                width: 6em;
                display: inline-block;
                margin: 3px 1em 3px 0;
                padding: 1px;
                background: #ddd;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="someId" class="color">
            <label><input name="someName" type="radio" value="#FF0000" checked="checked">Red</label>
            <label><input name="someName" type="radio" value="#FFA500">Orange</label>
            <label><input name="someName" type="radio" value="#FFFF00">Yellow</label>
            <label><input name="someName" type="radio" value="#008000">Green</label>
            <label><input name="someName" type="radio" value="#0000FF">Blue</label>
            <label><input name="someName" type="radio" value="#4B0082">Indigo</label>
            <label><input name="someName" type="radio" value="#EE82EE">Violet</label>
            <script>
                var options = document.getElementById("someId").getElementsByTagName("input");
                for (var option = 0; option < options.length; ++option) {
                    options[option].parentNode.style.borderColor = options[option].value;
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot from Firefox]